# Инициализация указателя в Си

Tags: c

Мне интересна ваша рецензия на таблицу вот этого ресурса
http://microsin.net/programming/dsp/difference-between-pointer-and-array-in-c.html
в пункте 2 таблицы сравнения

> 2. Указатель нельзя инициализировать при определении. Также нельзя при определении указателя проинициализировать память, на которую указывает указатель.

Что имеется здесь ввиду?

я могу присвоить адрес указателю в явном виде.

```
char* prt = (char*) 0xB8000000;
```

Указатель в данном коде указывает на область памяти 0xB8000000.
Я так понимаю утверждение "Указатель нельзя инициализировать при определении." не верно.

И автор статьи не прав ?

Comment: Судя по сопоставлению, они имеют в виду именно инициализацию в памяти, куда указывает указатель.

Comment: "Двоичный код, который генерируется для работы с указателями, отличается от кода, который генерируется при работе с массивами." - вот тут очень и очень спорно

Comment: Можно инициализировать и указатель и данные : `int _a [ 2 ] = { 4 , 5 } ; int * const pa = & _a [ 0 ] ;` Тут с какой точки зрения посмотреть.

Answer (score 0):

Автор статьи неправ.

Видимо он имеет в виду, что нельзя за одну строчку создать динамический массив и сразу указать его элементы.

Comment: Можно указать сразу на элемент.
https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/P8cfb3Yr9

Comment: @WinVictors Так я и говорю, автор неправ. Он видимо имел в виду, что нельзя вот это сделать в одну строчку: `int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * N); arr[0] = ...; arr[1] = ...; ...`.

Comment: Да, я тоже думаю он не прав.
Спасибо